# jQuery css height not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

For some reason the height is not being set in this piece of code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {



            jQuery('#main-content').css({'height': ((jQuery(window).height()))+'px'})
            jQuery('#nav-icons a').click(function(){

            jQuery('#nav-icons a').removeClass("active-icon");
            jQuery(this).addClass( "active-icon" );

            var toLoad = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #main-content';
            var toLoadSlider = jQuery(this).attr('href')+' #homepage-slider';

            jQuery('#main-content , #homepage-slider').fadeOut(1000, loadContent);
            function loadContent() {

                jQuery('#homepage-slider').empty().load(toLoadSlider) 
                jQuery('#main-content').empty().load(toLoad,'',showNewContent()) 

            }
            function showNewContent() {
                jQuery('#main-content , #homepage-slider').css({'height': ((jQuery(window).height()))+'px'}).hide().fadeIn(2000).removeAttr('id class');
            } 

            return false;
```

interestingly, the exact same line of code in the showNewContent() does set the height.

Comment: That part is working fine, it's this part that doesnt seem to function ' jQuery('#main-content').css({'height': ((jQuery(window).height()))+'px'})'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only logical reason for this is that `jQuery('#main-content')` in your first line is not the actual jQuery object representation of the DOM element of your choice.

You will have to figure that out yourself as to why things turn out this way.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot, thanks. I had the wrong id in there.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have

```
<div id="main-content">
  ... content
</div><!--main-content-->
```

This should do the trick :

```
var windowHeight = jQuery(window).height();
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $('#main-content').css({
        height: windowHeight
    });
    // other scripts
}); // ready
```

**<kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8meX5/)</kbd>**

Comment: you may need to add `$(window).resize()` if you want to change the height dynamically though.